# List<DateTime> in Lambda

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda

I am trying to list all dates using a Lambda expression. I have dates in a list but i would like to display using ForEach,  Here is my code

```
List<DateTime> yom = new List<DateTime>();

yom = InsuranceQuotations
  .OrderBy(x => x.mYear)
  .Select( x => x.mYear ?? DateTime.ParseExact("00/00/0000", "MM/dd/yyyy", provider))
  .ToList();

//error here!
var bday = Convert.ToDateTime(yom);

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
if (bday > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;

AgeOfVehicles = Convert.ToString(age);
```

The error says

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Can you give more informations about the object InsuranceQuotations and property mYear.

Comment: I am using LightSwitch. InsuranceQuotations is the GridView of a list of dates in the column "mYear".

Comment: On the line var bday = Convert.ToDateTime(yom), i think the problem is that you try to convert yom to datetime but it can't work because it's a list of date.

The function Convert.ToDateTime doesn't have an implementation for that kind of type.


[Existing convert function][1]

  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert collection of dates as single date object which indeed fails.

You should pick one date out of collection - maybe `.First()` or use `OrderBy(...)` and then select first. Note that result would be already of type `DateTime` and you don't need conversion.

Something like:

```
var bday = yom.OrderBy(x=>x).First();
```

Comment: @xdrone but you already have list of all dates...Sorry, I'm not sure what problem you have than.